# How can I get my Property Validation to work?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create some parameter attributes, but they are not running.

Here's some sample code of the attribute:

```cs
public abstract class ArgumentValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public abstract void Validate(object value, string argumentName);
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class NotNullAttribute : ArgumentValidationAttribute
{
    public override void Validate(object value, string argumentName)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argumentName);
        }
    }
}
```

and its usage:

```cs
public async Task Deactivate(int id, [NotNull][MaxLength(25)] string modifiedBy)
{
    // do something
}
```

However, when I call `Deactivate(5, null)` the attribute does not fire.  I've put breakpoints in my calling method and the attribute itself, but the breakpoint in the attribute never hits.

How do I get the attribute to call the `Validate` method?

Comment: Those attributes do not do what you think they do. They are metadata. To be utilized by an intermediary when invoking the said function. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What type of project is this? For example, if it's a model validation for MVC, you got to call this validation code in the DbContext.

Comment: I'm trying create a validation on method parameters in .NET Standard.  The idea is to attach attributes (such as DataAnnotations) to my method parameters in order to have specific requirements on those parameters (e.g. not null, maximum length, etc.)

Comment: AND I want to do the validation in the interface so that any implementations have the validation built in.  I'm trying to implement something similar to Code Contracts.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve, makes sense. However, how you are trying to achieve will not work, at least the way you intend it to. Remember attributes adds info to the metadata and NOT to the method itself. I'll demonstrate with a basic example of how attributes work.

For the sake of this example, I have simplified your `NotNullAttribute` to directly derive from `Attribute` -

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class NotNullAttribute : Attribute
{
    public void Validate(object value, string argumentName)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argumentName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now consider this `TestClass` which is `partial` and have your `Deactivate` method -

```
public partial class TestClass
{
    public void Deactivate(int id, [NotNull] string modifiedBy)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Second part of the `partial TestClass` is as follows -

```
public partial class TestClass
{
    public void CallDeactivate(int id, string modifiedBy)
    {
        var classType = typeof(TestClass);
        var deactivateMethod = classType.GetMethod("Deactivate");
        var parameterModifiedBy = deactivateMethod.GetParameters()[1];
        var notNullAttribute = parameterModifiedBy.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault();
        if (notNullAttribute.AttributeType == typeof(NotNullAttribute))
        {
            var attrObj = Activator.CreateInstance<NotNullAttribute>();
            attrObj.Validate(modifiedBy, parameterModifiedBy.Name);

            this.Deactivate(id, modifiedBy);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you don't call `Deactivate` directly instead you call 'CallDeactivate' -

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.CallDeactivate(12, null);
```

This will work and will throw `ArgumentNullException`. What `CallDeactivate` function do is read metadata of `Deactivate` function parameters and execute any functionality you want your attribute to define. Similar approach is used by EntityFramework to execute Data Contract attributes.

Hope this answers your question.